# Setting up an application environment using KIF

Tags: ios, ui-testing, kif

I’m using [KIF](https://github.com/kif-framework/KIF/) to do UI testing. The first thing I want to do is to cleanup all the cached data that could be around in the simulator. So I write the cleanup code in the `-beforeAll` method of my `KIFTestCase`. But this method is called *after* my app delegate `-application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` method is called. At this point it is too late, my app is already running and has already used the cached data.

I could modify my application code with something like `if (NSClassFromString(@"KIFTestCase") { … })` but this looks like a terrible solution to me.

Is there a clean way to execute some setup code *before* my app code is executed?

Note that I can’t use the new builtin UI testing feature of Xcode since I want to run tests on iOS 8.

Answer (score 0):

I would probably go with one of the suggested solutions (we personally check for `NSClassFromString("XCTest") != nil`)

But if both solutions don't work for you, and you don't mind some runtime magic, you can:

- Create a dynamic subclass of your `AppDelegate` class containing all the test logics, and use `object_setClass(appDelegate, [TestAppDelegate class])` to change the instance class (you will need to have an reference to the instance of your app delegate).
- Or simply swizzle the methods in questions in `+[TestHelper load]` so it'll happen before app delegation will fire (potentially calling the original implementation that you preserved prior to swizzling)

Hope it helps!

Comment: I generally use `#ifdef KIF_XCTEST` on the AppDelegate, that is defined as preprocessor macro

Answer (score 0):

There is no direct possibility that I know of, from a KIF test case, to do setup work before the app delegate method `-application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` runs.

On the other hand, you can trigger from your test case an app reset. The way I am doing that is the following:

- Do the setup work from the KIF test case (e.g. change the active language or set some special NSUserDefaults property).
- Send a notification using `NSNotificationCenter`, from the test case, to trigger an app reset

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"reset.app.state" object:self];
[tester waitForTimeInterval:1.0];
```

- In the app delegate we have previously registered ourselves for that notification

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(resetAppState:) name:@"reset.app.state" object:nil];
```

- Now we implement the `resetAppState:` method, where we instantiate again the app window and initial view controller. Here we can also do other setup tasks, if necessary.

```
- (void)resetAppState:(NSNotification*)notification
{
    NSLog(@"Reset app state for UI-Tests");

    // do other reset app state tasks, e.g. clean the caches & the like

    UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
    UIViewController *controller = [storyboard instantiateInitialViewController];
    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
    self.window.rootViewController = controller;

    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
}
```

This method seems to work reasonably well. I was able to use it e.g. to take screenshots in different languages, hence to set the app language and reset the app state from the test case.

I have prepared a sample project to illustrate how that works:
http://extrabright.com/dl/ResetAppState.zip

Comment: The link is broken, can you re-upload the example?